# Some images no longer showing up in Media Library

Tags: wordpress

My media Library is showing my images except for two (that I know about).  It says showing 8 of 8.  I see all 8.  There are no broken thumbnails or spinning Ajax wheels.  It's just that it only knows about 8 images.  The two it does not see are still displaying on my homepage and if I click to open image in a new window it opens with this path:

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/myimagename.jpg
```

Why did the media library stop knowing about this image.  I cannot pull it for a new page until I figure this out.  What could cause this?
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had copied content from my main site to a kind of sandbox site. The sandbox was pulling the images from the main site's upload directory. I just uploaded the missing images to my sandbox. They show up now.